# Cellspace package problem

Tags: cellspace

I have a table with pictures and want to center them vertically and horizontally in cell. I used `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellsapcebottomlimit` for that and I'm inserting them with custom command `\newcommand\cincludegraphics[2][]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}` and they're still touching the lines: [image]

How can I fix that?

Example:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Interpretowane pokrycia terenu}
    \label{tab:ndvi}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Zabudowa} & \textbf{Woda} & \textbf{Las} & \textbf{Gunt orny} & 
        \textbf{Uprawa trwała} \\ \hline
        \cincludegraphics[width=4.5cm]{../screeny/NDVI/NDVI_reklas_bud} & 
        \cincludegraphics[width=4.5cm]{../screeny/NDVI/NDVI_reklas_woda} & 
        \cincludegraphics[width=4.5cm]{../screeny/NDVI/NDVI_reklas_las} & 
        \cincludegraphics[width=4.5cm]{../screeny/NDVI/NDVI_reklas_rola} & 
        \cincludegraphics[width=4.5cm]{../screeny/NDVI/NDVI_reklas_laki} \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Probably using `valign=c` as an option to `\includegraphics`(needs `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`) instead of `\raisebox` helps. However this is just a guess. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you achieved the current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might give you an idea on how to combine `valign=c`, `cellspace` and nested tabulars:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ScScSc}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}Sc@{}}
\includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=c]{example-image} \\
\includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=c]{example-image}
\end{tabular} 
& \includegraphics[height=4.4cm, valign=c]{example-image} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}Sc@{}}
\includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=c]{example-image} \\
\includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=c]{example-image}
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.